# Compaire sqlite database date string "yyyy-MM-dd" with todays string in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime

I am storing `from_date` and `to_date` column in the database as `sdf` (**yyyy-MM-DD**). And I want to check if todays date is between these two dates or not.

My query is:

```
String where = Alarm.COL_TIME+" = "+"'"+time+"' AND Date(from_date) <= Date ('"+ today +"') AND Date(to_date) >= Date ('"+ today +"')";
```

But it shows nothing.
Please neglect time

how to do this??

Comment: You can do it more simple with the long value from every date.

Comment: how to compair long? is it simple compairing?

Comment: simple: You got Your dates, these You can convert to long with the simpleDateFormat.parse() method. If You have this longs, just: if(todayLong>fromDateLong) and if(todayLong<toDateLong)...

Comment: it is too simple! Thank You @Opiatefuchs ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say You have a String as a Date like You said "yyyy-MM-dd". Lets say it´s "2014-12-03". Then, parse it to a long value with:

```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault());

   String todayString = "2014-12-03";
   String fromString = "2014-12-01";
   String toString = "2014-12-05";

   Date todayDate = format.parse(todayString);
   Long today = todayDate.getTime();

   Date fromDate = format.parse(fromString);
   Long from = fromDate.getTime();

   Date toDate = format.parse(toString);
   Long to = toDate.getTime();
```

With this You have all three long values and can compair:

```
   if(today>fromDate&&today<toDate){
     //then today is between these days
   }
```

Comment: what You mean with don´t know how.. :) ? It´s an easy thing...Date.getTime() returns the current time in milliseconds...and that´s all. So You got the three dates in milliseconds, the older date is smaller than the newer date..

Comment: Actually I did the same thing before asking this question, but after copy past this it starts running correctly! :)

Comment: yep....I stumpled ov er so many issues in the beginning, just because I haven´t seen little things..  :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will store today's date in your `today` variable, in yyyy-MM-dd format:

```
// Imports
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

// Above your "String where = Alarm..." assignment
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

Comment: my problem is not how to get current date, it is how to compair!

Comment: I created a test SQLite table with rows containing dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format in `from_date` and `to_date` columns. I then tested my code sample to provide today's date (in the same format) in your `today` variable to your `WHERE` clause (ignoring `Alarm.COL_TIME`, as you suggested), and the query correctly returned the matching rows.  **Your `WHERE` clause above compares the dates correctly**, so if you're not getting any results back, the issue is probably elsewhere in your query or in your data.  Hope this helps.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM testtable
WHERE Date(from_date) <= Date ('2015-02-21') AND Date(to_date) >= Date ('2015-02-21');`